# AWS boto v2.32.0 - List tags for an ASG

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, autoscaling

I am trying to use boto v2.32.0 to list the tags on a particular ASG

something simple like this is obviously not working (especially with the lack of a filter system):

```
import boto.ec2.autoscale

asg = boto.ec2.autoscale.connect_to_region('ap-southeast-2')
tags = asg.get_all_tags('asgname')
print tags
```

or:

```
asg = boto.ec2.autoscale.connect_to_region('ap-southeast-2')
group = asg.get_all_groups(names='asgname')
tags = asg.get_all_tags(group)
print tags
```

or:

```
asg = boto.ec2.autoscale.connect_to_region('ap-southeast-2')
group = asg.get_all_groups(names='asgname')
tags = group.get_all_tags()
print tags
```

Without specifying an '`asgname`', it's not returning every ASG. Despite what the documentation says about returning a token to see the next page, it doesn't seem to be implemented correctly - especially when you have a large number of ASG's and tags per ASG.

Trying something like this has basically shown me that the token system appears to be broken. it is not "looping" through all ASG's and tags before it returns "None":

```
asg = boto.ec2.autoscale.connect_to_region('ap-southeast-2')

nt = None

while ( True ):
        tags = asg.get_all_tags(next_token=nt)
        for t in tags:
               if ( t.key == "MyTag" ):
                       print t.resource_id
                       print t.value
        if ( tags.next_token == None ):
                break
        else:
                nt = str(tags.next_token)
```

Has anyone managed to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually answered my own question by creating a work around using the amazon cli. Since there has been no activity on this question since the day I asked it I am posting this workaround as a solution.

```
import os
import json

## bash command
awscli = "/usr/local/bin/aws autoscaling describe-tags --filters Name=auto-scaling-group,Values=" + str(asgname)

output = str()
# run it
cmd = os.popen(awscli,"r")
while 1:
    # get tag lines
    lines = cmd.readline()
    if not lines: break
    output += lines

# json.load to manipulate
tags = json.loads(output.replace('\n',''))
```

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is available in AWS using the [AutoScaling DescribeTags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTags.html) API call, but unfortunately boto does not completely implement this call.

You should be able to pass a [Filter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/APIReference/API_Filter.html) with that API call to only get the tags for a specific ASG, but if you have a look at the [boto source code for get_all_tags()](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/fb4aeec5ef11142c4a0550056b989bf655282adf/boto/ec2/autoscale/__init__.py#L816-L842) (v2.32.1), the filter is not implemented:

```
:type filters: dict 
:param filters: The value of the filter type used
                to identify the tags to be returned.  NOT IMPLEMENTED YET.
```

(quote from the source code mentioned above).

Comment: Hi @dcro , I saw that but was hoping someone might know a work around using the list returned by "get_all_tags". so far I think I've found that the token system is not very well implemented.

Comment: I've updated my question according to my new findings. hoping someone will have some input.

Comment: To anyone still reaching this answer, it still hasn't been implemented as of v2.35.1, and I had to use the accepted aws-cli solution below.